# with Spring hibernate / jpa How to query multiple columns with multiple search criterias

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

For example I have a table (name = SampleTable) with columns:
id,a: varchar,b: varchar,c: varchar,d: varchar

I want to be able to query such that I can select rows by multiple columns with multiple selection criterias.
Example:

```
listOf(
   (a: "a value 1", b: "b value 1", c: "c value 1", d: "d value 1"),
   (a: "a value 2", b: "b value 2", c: "c value 2", d: "d value 2"),
   (a: "a value 3", b: "b value 3", c: "c value 3", d: "d value 3"),
   ...
): List<(varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar)>
```

I want to be able to search something like:

```
@Query("""
select * 
From SampleTable as s
where (
   (s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d) in :column_a_b_c_d_selectionCriterias
)
""")
fun selectByMultipleCriteria(column_a_b_c_d_selectionCriterias: List<(varchar,varchar,varchar,varchar)>)
```

I know that I cant do it like this with above code,
but is there another way?
I think I may have to use Spring Specifications, but would like a simpler method :p

Comment: use CRUD repository query method : 
findByAInAndBInAndCIn( List<String> list1, List<String> list2, List<String> list2).

For complex query you can you built in Spring Specifications or DSL library like QueryDsl, JOOQ..

Comment: @meobeo173 , this will not do what I want. Even if each list paramater to the method was in the same order (to match the row to multiple columns), you would not get what you wanted with that query. It would match rows that contain atleast 1 matching column value from each list , which is not what I needed.